# How to infer data based on key in input parameters?

Tags: typescript

Not quite sure why this doesn't work.

```
type someTypes = "a" | "b" | "c"
type otherTypes = "d" | "e" | "f"

interface someObject   {
  foo: string
}

type Data<K> = K extends someTypes ? string : someObject

const doSomething = <K extends someTypes|otherTypes>(key:K, data: Data<K>) => {
  switch (key) {
    case "b":
      console.log(data.length);
      break;
    case "e":
      console.log(data.foo);
      break;
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that with some key values data has one shape, while others give another shape. If this would be overloading the signatures would be any of these:

```
const doSomething = (key: someTypes, data: string) => { }
const doSomething = (key: otherTypes, data: someObject) => { }
```

[ts-playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAzg9gWwgFXBGUC8UBEBDHKAH1wCNCScBjHAWAChRIo5gALCAJ1Ug2xwAmFXBGE4AZnXoMAlgDtgXcXirR4SAPKkAVhCrAohgN4ND4uHABcsYJ3kBzBgF8GDJtAAieYHgA8AaQA+LCh-KAgAD0U5AQx1FDQMAH4bOzl7KGt4rV19V3oqODkYAwE4AGVECHYHEIDwqIgYuKqedCJWDm5EwIAKAGsIEEt-ABooAW88ay8fAMCASixgk3pDGAB3GWAqNigBoaXVw0MqPBhoHHJLUxPTovgAGwgAOke4e17Jnzem+3YFgBuW53UicCB4frAtYnM4XEQ4G4wu6FYpwZ5vD5fKYvcxwIEgk5giFQ24uejkhhAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that type parameter `K` [cannot be narrowed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) with the [control flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) (the `switch`). An example:

```
function fooGeneric<T extends "a" | "b">(t: T) {
  if (t === "a") {
    t // t is still T extends "a" | "b" 
  }
}

function fooConcrete(t: "a" | "b") {
  if (t === "a") {
    t // t is now "a" as expected
  }
}
```

The conditional type `Data<K>` will not be narrowed as well, so TS doesn't know how the function parameter `data` looks like in the branches of the `switch` statement.

Solution: It is fine and safe to just use a type assertion here, as you already checked the value of `key`.

```
const doSomething = <K extends someTypes|otherTypes>(key:K, data: Data<K>) => {
  switch (key) {
    case "b":
      console.log((data as Data<"b">).length);
      break;
    case "e":
      console.log((data as Data<"e">).foo);
      break;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make `doSomething` concrete and use a mapping `Data` type (this one alters function signature):

```
type DataAlt = { [K in someTypes]: string } & { [K in otherTypes]: someObject }

const doSomethingAlt = (key: keyof DataAlt, data: DataAlt) => {
  switch (key) {
    case "b":
      const resB = data[key] // const resB: string
      resB.length // ✅
      break;
    case "e":
      const resE = data[key] // const resE: someObject
      resE.foo // ✅
      break;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=34&ssc=2&pln=21&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAzg9gWwgFXBGUC8UBEBDHKAH1wCNCScBjHAWAChRIo5gALCAJ1Ug2xwAmFXBGE4AZnXoMAlgDtgXcXirR4SAPKkAVhCrAohgN4ND4uHABcsYJ3kBzBgF8GDJtAAieYHgA8AaQA%20LCh-KAgAD0U5AQx1FDQMAH4bOzl7KGt4rV19V3oqODkYAwE4AGVECHYHEIDwqIgYuKqedCJWDm5EwIAKAGsIEEt-ABooAW88ay8fAMCASixgk3pDGAB3GWAqNigBoaXVw0MqPBhoHHJLUxPTovgAGwgAOke4e17eyZ8oc6hZn4rjhFm8mvZ2AsANy3O6kTgQPD9GFrE5nC4iHA3VF3QrFODPN4fL4-PB-DCA3w4USg8xwaGwk7wxHI24uejstxoAFTACCjwM2CMUAA2mF5LBWokALpZWy1JxQABkUGFYqgEs6XDaMFlks0Oj0Bk5BQepQqVRq6X5gv2g2GUHtcHEPJ8NvGpJmfIFS0wK1um22uzth1VjPRl2ujPuxQMCJgACEQqSRfbpVAAPQZqB4kpQeMJuVpRw4k4FsHpdiZ7OAUHJo1BmUiUbjzpdRNi7jG8-GAKLJqapobprM5s359A9rJVHJG%20u9l506tQOulwyN1mo9nsoA)